# Reversing a phrase recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

I got an assignment recently that asked me to create a program that reverses an input phrase using recursion (in Java) and outputs it. For example, given an input "THIS IS A SENTENCE" the program would output "SENTENCE A IS THIS".

However, the assignment also states that I cannot use any storage or Java collections except for a single local String variable inside the recursive function. Therefore, the Java stack will be holding all the words from the input.

The problem I am running into is implementing the recursion properly. Declaring a String variable locally overwrites any value I had stored in it previously, so I'm not really sure how to implement a local variable without disrupting the recursive calls. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: HINT: reverse ("a b c d") = reverse("b c d") + "a"; reverse("a") = "a";

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the right logic, except that the else block needs to return a value rather than simply storing it in the local variable

```
return reversePhrase(scanner) + string;
```

You might also want to add a space:

```
return reversePhrase(scanner) + " " + string;
```